# C# - Auto Scale Chart Axis

Tags: c#, mschart

The AxisX works well and only shows the last 50 seconds. **My problem** is that the AxisY doesnt scale automatically and when the values change from 0 to 500 for example it shrinks a lot. I also want to show a proper interval.

```
 private void timercharts_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        grafico_pos.Add((int)distancia_atual);
        grafico_pos.Add((int)distancia_desejada);


        chart_pos.Series[0].Points.AddXY(tempo, distancia_atual);
        chart_pos.Series[1].Points.AddXY(tempo, distancia_desejada);




        chart_pos.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = (grafico_pos.Max() - grafico_pos.Min()/5);

        chart_pos.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum = grafico_pos.Min() - 15;
        chart_pos.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = grafico_pos.Max() + 15;


        if (tempo > 50)
        {
            chart_pos.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = tempo - 50;


            grafico_pos.RemoveAt(0);
            grafico_pos.RemoveAt(0);

        }

        chart_pos.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();


        tempo++;

    }
```

So basically I want to scale the AxisY based on Max and Min of the points in the last 50 seconds. and adjust the interval correctly.

[image]

Comment: You describe rather well what you want. All you need now is to do it..

Comment: That's what I tried with my code. But the graph interval is not correct and and max and min are also not updating

Comment: @TaW this code is working now. But the values min max and intervals of the axisY disappear

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/6d0a140666e0794cc0c2f5ef0833a6f8.png

Comment: As you can see the axisY dissapeared

Comment: It hasn't disappeared. It only seems to have an Interval that is too large. Check your calculations!